# Received memory warning when saving data on a background thread

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management, crash, nsmanagedobject

I have many objects in `NSMutableArray`(>2500) and when I save it, app crashes (received memory warning x3).

```
    NSLog(@"start");
    NSInteger saveTemp = 0;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    if ([data length] > 0 && err == nil)
    {
        MyClass* rcust;
        NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSMutableArray* cust = [respStr JSONValue];
        for(NSDictionary *v in cust)
        {
            if([dataProvider getClassById:[[v valueForKey:@"Id"] integerValue] error:nil] == nil)
            {
                rcust = [dataProvider createClass];
                rcust.clsId = [v valueForKey:@"Id"];
            }
            else
            {
                rcust = [dataProvider getClassById:[[v valueForKey:@"Id"] integerValue] error:nil];
            }
            rcust.cstZip = [v valueForKey:@"Zip"] == [NSNull null]? @"": [v valueForKey:@"Zip"];

            saveTemp++;
            if(saveTemp > 1000)
            {
                NSLog(@"save");
               [dataProvider saveContext];
                saveTemp = 0;
            }
        }
        [dataProvider saveContext];
    }
```

Here the `saveContext` method

```
- (void)saveContext {
    NSError*err = nil;
    if(![[self managedObjectContext] save:&err])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", err, [err userInfo]);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I added code to the method and there you are.

```
2013-03-21 15:18:54.641  start
2013-03-21 15:19:31.843  save
2013-03-21 15:23:21.126  save
```

i.e. Data saving is getting slower and after a while, the application crashes.

Comment: When do you receive memory warning? Try to post some other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you have >2500 customers being returned from that NSURLRequest. By the time you've populated the `cust` array, you have four copies of that data (as NSData, as NSString, as NSMutableArray, and in your NSManagedObjectContext).

Use @autoreleasepool to wrap your NSData and NSString conversions. Once you have done your `-JSONValue` call, you don't need those representations anymore.

Then, wrap your processing loop in an @autoreleasepool also. That will allow intermediate results (even the ones you can't see) to be freed.

Finally, when you do your saveContext, do a -reset on the managed object context too.

Two other notes for you:

Your check of the NSError parameter in line 4 is incorrect. For methods that have an NSError** parameter, the NSError return value is undefined if the operation succeeds. The logic should be `if (data.length > 0)` then proceed, otherwise examine NSError. See NSURLConnection's class reference.

Also, your `getClassById` method appears to violate Cocoa naming standards. If the method begins with the word `get`, it must return its results by reference in parameters. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF.

Comment: Thanks. It solved a problem with leakage of memory. But all the same in a cycle preservation goes all more slowly and more slowly. How I can accelerate process of saving of data?

Comment: Is it actually the `saveContext` call that is slow? Or some other part? This would be a good time to fire up Instruments, and to turn on `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` (see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/11/debugging-core-data-on-the-iphone.html). I notice that your misnamed `getClassById:error` is called twice for some iterations. What does it do?